# Ansible Playbook Permission

Tags: ssh, unix, ansible

I have one host abc.com where I have downloaded playbooks from GitHub.
There are multiple users which can connect to abc.com but I want to restrict the playbook execution for specific user X.

So that only X can execute the playbooks not the other users.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

- Create new user,
- set 0750 to new home directory,
- put playbooks into new homedir,
- allow your user to run `sudo -u newuser ansible example.yml`.